# Grails app is reloading on css changes

Tags: spring, grails

I am developing a Grails app in Groovy/Grails Tool Suite. I start my server by simply running the vFabric tc Server that comes built in. Unfortunately, when I make css changes, the entire server reloads. This doesn't happen with gsp changes. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You probably don't need to deploy to tc server if you're developing your app. Try using 'run-app' (right click your project, select 'run as' or 'debug as' and then choose 'run-app').

Or you can just open a grails prompt and do 'run-app' from there.